# Executar ciclo FOR dentro de outro ciclo FOR

Tags: java, for

```
for(int g=0;g<vl.VerbsList.length;g++){ // primeiro loop ok
    for(int h=0;h<TextParts.length;h++){ //segundo loop deveria ser executada por inteiro
        for(int j =0;j<BaseWord.length();j++){
              try{
                  if(BaseWord.charAt(j) == TextParts[h].charAt(j)){
                      System.out.println("BaseWord "+BaseWord);
                      System.out.println("TextParts "+TextParts[h]);
                      System.out.println("h "+h);
                      TempPoints += 1;
                  }
              } catch(Exception e){
                  TempPoints = 0;
                  j = BaseWord.length();
              }
          }

        //Ciclo Text Parts
        if(TempPoints > Points) {
            Word = TextParts[h];
            TempPosition = h;
            Points = TempPoints;
            TempPoints = 0;
            BaseWord = "";
            System.out.println("Points: "+Points);
        } else {
            TempPoints = 0;
            BaseWord = "";
        }
    }
    //Ciclo de Verbal List
}
```

**Quero que em uma execução desse ciclo:**

```
for(int g=0;g<vl.VerbsList.length;g++){
```

**O programa execute todo esse outro ciclo:**

```
for(int h=0;h<TextParts.length;h++){
```

*(A primeira for tem que esperar a segunda acabar para continuar)*

**Assim eu consigo comparar os caracteres de um texto com os caracteres do outro texto.**

**Porem a primeira for não esta esperando a segunda terminar**

**Teste:**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**O valor de "h" sempre e 0.**
**Isso significa que a for sempre esta recomeçando.**

**Onde eu Errei?**

*(O código do tópico não e o código completo)*

Answer (score 1):

Eu consegui resolver.
Aparentemente o erro estava na hora de resetar a variável "BaseWord"

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
    /*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package dino.ai;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

/**
 *
 * @author Matheus Markies
 */
public class VerbDetector extends Thread{

    String Text;
    String[] TextParts;

    List<String> SimilarVerbs = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> TextVerbs = new ArrayList<String>();

    List<Integer> VerbsPositions = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int TempPosition;

    boolean Analyze;

    int TempPoints;
    int Points;

    int b;

    String Word;
    String BaseWord;
    int Proof;

    public void run(){

        while (Analyze) {            

    Verbs vl = new Verbs();
    TextParts = Text.split(" ");

    for(int g=0;g<vl.VerbsList.length;g++){
        BaseWord = "";
        if(vl.VerbsList[g].length() > 2){
       for(int i = 0;i<vl.VerbsList[g].length();i++){
                if(i<(vl.VerbsList[g].length()-2)){
                    BaseWord = BaseWord + vl.VerbsList[g].charAt(i);
                }
            }
        }else{
            BaseWord = vl.VerbsList[g];
        }

        for(int h=0;h<TextParts.length;h++){


            //if(TextParts[h].length()>vl.VerbsList[g].length()){
                for(int j =0;j<BaseWord.length();j++){

                  try{
                  if(BaseWord.charAt(j) == TextParts[h].charAt(j)){
                      //System.out.println("BaseWord "+BaseWord);
                      //System.out.println("TextParts "+TextParts[h]);
                      //System.out.println("Tamanho TextParts: " + TextParts.length);
                      //System.out.println("Tamanho VerbsList: "+vl.VerbsList.length);

                      //System.out.println("h "+h);
                       TempPoints += 1;
                  }else{

                  }
                  }catch(Exception e){
                      TempPoints = 0;
                      j++;
                  }

                }

            //}else{
             //   for(int j =0;j<TextParts[h].length();j++){
               //   try{
                //    if(TextParts[h].charAt(j) == vl.VerbsList[g].charAt(j)){
                //       TempPoints += 1; 
                 // }
                 // }catch(Exception e){
                   //   TempPoints = 0;
                  //    j++;
                  //}
                //}
            //}
            //Ciclo Text Parts

            if(TempPoints > Points){
            Word = TextParts[h];
            TempPosition = h;
            Points = TempPoints;
            TempPoints = 0;
            //BaseWord = "";
            System.out.println("Points: "+Points);
            }else{
            TempPoints = 0;
            //BaseWord = "";
            }
             //System.out.println("h "+h);


       }

        //Ciclo de Verbal List
        if(vl.VerbsList[g].length() > 2){
        Proof = (100*Points)/(vl.VerbsList[g].length() - 2);
        }else{
        Proof = (100*Points)/(vl.VerbsList[g].length());   
        }
        if(Proof >= 90){
            System.out.println("Proof: "+Proof);
            for(int i = 0;i<SimilarVerbs.size();i++){
                if(SimilarVerbs.get(i) == vl.VerbsList[g]){
                    b +=1;
                }
            }
            if(b == 0){
            SimilarVerbs.add(vl.VerbsList[g]);
            TextVerbs.add(Word);
            VerbsPositions.add(TempPosition);

            System.out.println("SimilarVerbs "+SimilarVerbs);

            }else{
             b = 0;
            }
            Points = 0;
        }else{
            Points = 0;
        }

    }

    for(int i=0;i<SimilarVerbs.size();i++){
    LanguageProcessingManager.CA.SetSimilarWord(SimilarVerbs.get(i));
    LanguageProcessingManager.CA.SetVerb(TextVerbs.get(i));   
    }

    LanguageProcessingManager.GOSI.SetText(Text);
    int size = VerbsPositions.size();
    int[] result = new int[size];
    Integer[] temp = VerbsPositions.toArray(new Integer[size]);
    for (int n = 0; n < size; ++n) {
    result[n] = temp[n];
    }
    LanguageProcessingManager.GOSI.SetVerbsPositions(result);
    Analyze = false;

            try {
                Thread.sleep(10);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(VerbDetector.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }

    }//Analyze

    }

    public void SetTextAnalyze(String SetValue){
        Text = SetValue;
        //SimilarVerbs.clear();
        //TextVerbs.clear();
        Analyze = true;
    }
    public List<String> GetSimilarVerbs(){
    return SimilarVerbs;
    }
    public List<String> GetVerbs(){
    return TextVerbs;
    }
    public int[] GetVerbsPosition(){

    int size = VerbsPositions.size();
    int[] result = new int[size];
    Integer[] temp = VerbsPositions.toArray(new Integer[size]);
    for (int n = 0; n < size; ++n) {
    result[n] = temp[n];
    }

    return result;
    }

}
```

Esse e o código inteiro para quem quiser dar uma olhada.

Obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Teoricamente, for aninhado trabalham da forma como você quer, ou seja, para cada iteração dor externo há todas as iterações possíveis do for interno. No entanto, coisas aparentemente estranhas podem ocorrer se as partes condicionais dos for não forem bem projetadas. Você tem certeza que o tamanho definido por VerbsList.length é maior que um (1)? E de TextParts.length? O que parece é que VerbsList é maior maior que um (1) - parece ser de tamanho dez (10), mas TextParts é de tamanho um (1), daí que está sempre trazendo o índice 0 (uma iteração). Aplique um System.out.println("Tamanho: " + TextParts.lenght) para ver qual é o tamanho desse array. Qualquer coisa atualize a sua pergunta esclarecendo melhor de onde vem esses arrays.

Obs.: é uma boa prática nomear variáveis com letra minúscula.

Comment: https://imgur.com/PmGw6gT (TextParts.length = 11)(vl.VerbsList.length = 5000)

Comment: Veja essas partes: VerbsList.length, TextParts.length, BaseWord.length(). Consegue ver alguma diferença?

Comment: Poste o código inteiro para que possamos testar.